# Delay not firing when trigger of a pickbranch or in a parallel sequence

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow, hosted in a workflow service host, that can have one of three paths through a particular section of it. I have created it with a Pick activity that contains three PickBranch activities. Two of the three have a ReceiveSendReply as the trigger, while one has a Delay.

At this point, I can make the workflow continue by calling either of the receives, but if I attempt to let the delay timeout, it never does. I have also tried it in a vanilla parallel activity - again, either of the receives will move the workflow forward, but the delay never times out / triggers.

Everything I've read suggests that it SHOULD work, but it is not. I have looked at the workflow trace logs and I can see that the delay is executing, but it never comes back.

```
146: Activity [160] "Delay Sequence" scheduled child activity [201] "Delay"
147: Activity [201] "Delay" is Executing
{
    Arguments
        Duration: 00:10:00
}
```

Is there any other way I can model this. It seems that the Pick should do what I need, but I cannot make it work. For completeness, I have created a very simple application where I modeled this with two receives as triggers of a pick branch, and a delay as the trigger for another, and it WORKS there...

Any help/ideas would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I found was that I had placed a CorrelationInitializer in the wrong spot, and it appears that it interfered with the Delay's callback mechanism. Once I moved the initializer into the correct spot for what I was doing, the delay started working. Thanks for your input and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Has the workflow persisted and unloaded? A delay activity would have triggered that, but if you are not running in a service you may have to handle the loading of the workflow on your own because, well it's unloaded.

Comment: Sorry - I should have stated this (and have edited the post): the workflow is hosted in a workflow service host. The workflow has persisted and unloaded. However, everything I've seen says that when a workflow is hosted in a workflow service host (that is the case in my situation) that when a delay is in play, the workflow service host is responsible for checking to see if the delay has expired and resuming if necessary. Is that not the case?

Comment: I believe that to be correct. And yet... If you would manually load the workflow would the delay fire?

Comment: I spent a little time trying to recreate your scenario... but failed! I was able to use a pick with a bookmark and a delay activity as an escalation, a very common scenario. I added the behavior to unload on idle, but did not add persistence. Worked as expected. Then I ran it under Appfabric for persistence and monitoring, also setting to unload on idle. Still worked. Then I started a new instance, confirmed it was pending on the bookmark killed IIS. As expected, the delay did not fire. But as soon as the apppool started again, the delay kicked off as expected. Are you using persistence?